# Can we use "have" with "dance"?

Tags: sentence-combination

Is this correct, If I say "**They're having a dance.**" instead of "**They're dancing.**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Having a dance"  is not generally used in this sense.  It is (rarely) used to mean "organising a dance party".

> The Women's Institute will be having their annual dance on the 1st of June, and are seeking gentlemen partners who are able to tango.

> I saw a group of teenagers having a dance around a portable speaker in the school common room.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen "have a dance" used to mean "dance", but I don't think I've seen it used in a mutual sense. Someone might ask "May I have this dance?" to mean "May I dance? with you?", so "We had a dance" is a logical extension of that, but it's not common.

Comment: Have a dance...? Have a song....??  I may be poor at it for not knowing these...